History of a Peculiar Notation for Function and Relation Composition
Ginzburg's "Algebraic Theory of Automata" (1968) uses a very unusual notation for functions, function composition, and relations, and I'm curious about its history and if it's still used today.

Given a function $f$, the book uses $xf$ to denote $f(x)$.
Thus, $fg$ represents $g \circ f$.
If $R$ is a relation, $xR$ denotes $\{y : x R y\}$.
If $R$ is a relation and $X$ is a set, $XR$ denotes $\{y: \exists x \in X: x R y\}$
As such, $Xf$ denotes $\{f(x) | x \in X\}$
Given two relations $R$, $S$, $RS$ is a relation with $x RS z$ if $\exists y: x R y \text{ and } y S z$. This notation is compatible with function composition above.

This notation, although hard to decipher to those not used to it, is very well suited to the study of semigroups and automata. I remember seeing it in a few other texts on automata theory from around the same time.

Is it still used by anyone today?
Are there any interesting stories about its adoption / abandonment?


At one time, the convention of writing functions after their arguments was fairly popular. The main (perhaps only) reason was the second item  on your list: $fg$  would mean "first $f$ and then $g$"; the functions are applied in the order in which they're written.

John Fraleigh uses that function notation in his A First Course in Abstract Algebra.
It takes a while to get used to that notation, but it's not so bad once you get used to it. I found the real problem, if you could call it that, was switching back and forth when I would move to other textbooks etc.
It struck me as a bit bizarre as well.
